# Animate MKCircleRenderer

Tags: ios, animation, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkcircle

I want to create pulsing + fading animation on the map view. I know that it can be done by using/subclassing `MKCircleView`, however, it is now depricated. Any way to do it with `MKCircleRenderer` or any other "hacky", but not deprecated/unrecommended, way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe that this is a very "specific" topic and not many people have encountered such. I found a hard-hacky way to do it using a timer and just redrawing the circle each time. I don't know whether it is the best way, but it certainly  works. I would not advice to use it for many MKCircles though, performance may not be ideal.